# get a character select if its int or str or a symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

hi im having this problem this is my code rn but it wont do anything or just say its a int or a str

```py
b=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
c=['&','!','@','#','$','%']

a = input("Enter here :")

if type(a) ==int:
    print("number")

if a==b:
    print("word")

if a ==c:
    print("symbol")
```

I tried putting a int or a str behind a input thing but that didn't solve the prob
i wanna write a code as clean as possible and not with list cuz they are long and hard to make.

Comment: `if a in b: print("word")`

Comment: For your second and third `if` you need: `if a in b:` etc

Comment: What is the problem? What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do instead? Please [edit] your question to give more details.

Comment: There're many problems in the code.  But first is the ```input``` is taken as ```str```, and you cannot pass 1st test.  Maybe try ```isinstance(a, int)``` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple things you need to know.
First of all, output of input function is always a string. So even though you enter a number like 523, python will see it as a string: "523".

You can use isnumeric to check if it can be converted into numbers like:

```
if(a.isnumeric()):print("number")
```

Secondly, if b is an array and you check equality of an array and a string which is a. In this case result will always be False.
So you should check like this

```
if(a in b):
    ...
```

and it's also same for c

Answer (score 1):

The question is worded a little strangely but i'll give it a go. B is a list, so saying a==b will not be true if it is a word. you may be looking to see if the charater passed in (a) is IN list b. for that you will want to do `if a in b`. Also i believe all of the inputs a will come in as a string, so the first line `if type(a) == int` will never be true.
[image]

I would most likely use the is numeric function on the string input

```
if a.isnumeric():
```

you have some more work to do, I hope this was helpful and wish you luck